# Screen sharing through a browser (like Google Meet) with remote control, on Linux, without additional software

Tags: screen-sharing, remote-control

We tried **Zoom** and **AnyDesk**, but they do not work because of video driver issues (my friend has Nvidia GPU).

Google Meet works! But we want remote control. **Chrome Remote Desktop** wants to install deb, but we use **Gentoo Linux**.

We tried **x2go** but it needs ip address, and my friend cannot edit his router settings in order to pass the internal ip:port to outside, so because of this we also cannot use `ssh -X`.

Answer (score 1):

Also [Zoho Assist](https://www.zoho.com/assist) has this funcionality.

It has two flavors: *Remote Support* and *Unattended Remote Access* (but the client needs an installation for it).

And lot of features:

- File transfer
- Instant Chat
- Schedule Sessions
- Multi-Monitor Navigation
- Voice and Video Chat
- Reboot and Reconnect

And

- Bulk Deployment
- Diagnostic tools
- Remote Power Options
- Wake on LAN
- Session Recording
- Session Confirmation

Comment: Not in Gentoo repository :( https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/search?q=zoho

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it with help of [Getscreen.me](https://getscreen.me/) software. This remote desktop works from browser and don't need to instal additional program. Works on Linux as well.

Comment: When you offer a program you have relation with, you **MUST** disclose such affiliation.

Comment: Besides, the website seems to require a program to be installed on the server side, with only the client being browser-only.